# SSRS 2008 - How to hide row group column with user-defined grouping?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that we allow the user to choose a field to group on. This is a parameter and the grouping works properly.

However, if no grouping is selected (the default case), the row group column is still displayed. You can hide static columns by setting a visibility expression, but I can't right-click and hide the row group column whenever no grouping has been set.

How can I hide the row group column in SSRS 2008 when the users haven't chosen a field to group on BUT still display it when they have?

Answer (score -1):

Yes On a group you cannot set the column visibility directly. However you can go to advanced options then set the hidden property and set it to true or false or expression.
If you want to shrink the table then set column shrink true.

hope it helps